# How do I translate this line of code to a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

assuming 'words' has consists of lists of strings

```
[len(i) for i in words]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
for i in words:
    len(i) = len(i) + 1
```

Comment: Your code already *has* a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
[len(i) for i in words]
```

This line is already a for loop, compressed in one line.
The multiple line for loop equivalent will be:

```
lengths = []
for i in words:
    lengths.append(len(i))
```

This will store the result in the variable `lengths` which is a `list`.

It is better to use the former as it does not need an extra variable, is of only one line, and is more pythonic.